# Create ES6 module 'equivalent' using webpack output.target options

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, node-modules, es6-modules

Firstly, apologies! I struggled summing up the issue in the title so please feel free to amend.

#### The problem

Suppose I have two ES6 files that expose default functions

```
// file_1.js
export default function(){ /* do the thing */ }

// file_2.js
export default function(){ /* do the other thing */ }
```

Now I bundle `file_1` into a module using webpack (w/ babel loader) using the following output configuration

```
// webpack config 1.
{
   ...
   entry : '/path/to/file_1.js'
   output : {
      path: '/where/it/goes/',
      filename : 'main.js',
      library: 'my_component',
      libraryTarget: 'var'
   }
}
```

I also have a minimal `package.json` so it can be imported as a npm module `{ name: 'file_1', main: 'main.js' }`

Now the challenge comes when I want to bundle together the code from `file_1` and the module `file_2` and a uniform manner.

```
// master_entry.js

const components = {
    file_1 : require('file_1'),
    file_2 : require('/path/to/file_2')
}
```

If I bundle the above and look at the resulting form of `components` it looks like so

```
console.log(components.file_1)
// outputs
Module {__esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module" }
```

```
console.log(components.file_2)
// outputs
Module {default: f, __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module" }
```

Hence for `file_2` (which was not prebundled) I have the default function available - which is what I want. How do I achieve the same thing when bundling `file_1`?

I have tried playing around with the webpack `output` options such as `library`, `libraryTarget`, `libraryExport`. However I am a bit lost and have spent far to long in the docs now - hence the cry for help!

Thanks in advance.

#### For clarity

`file_1.js` `-webpack->` package `file_1` (entry point `file_1.js`)
`master_entry` `-webpack->` `main.js`

I.e, webpack is running first on `file_1.js` and subsequently upon the combination of importing the `file_1` package and `file_2.js`.

Comment: can you provide us a link to the repository? Also, im not sure why you specified the entry to be file1 instead of master_entry.js.

Comment: @StavAlfi added a clarification above. Webpack is running twice. First to produce a package and then to bundle a file that consumes that package.

Comment: @StavAlfi there is no single repository. If I had the ability to change all the moving parts I could just just webpack it in one go without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution ;)

```
// file_1.js
export default function file1(){ console.log('file_1') }

// file_2.js
export default function file2(){ console.log('file_2') }
```

The webpack.config.js should look like this

```
entry: {
  file1: './sources/js/file_1.js',
  file2: './sources/js/file_2.js',
},
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: './[name].js',
  library: '[name]',
  libraryExport: 'default',
  libraryTarget: 'umd', // you can use libraries everywhere, e.g requirejs, node 
  umdNamedDefine: true,
},
```

From now you have access to:

```
<script>
  new file1(); // console.log show file_2
  new file2(); // console.log show file_2
</script>
```

You can also now pass options to functions. Take a look at my [solution](https://github.com/tomik23/autosuggest)

Comment: @Grzegprz  .T - I can't test this as we went down another route in the end. I have upvoted and if anyone else lands here and confirms that it works I will happily accept the answer. Thanks for posting!