# How to bundle ES6 modules in multiple files into a single ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

#### The question

I have an ES6 module that uses another bunch of ES6 modules.

E.g

```
import { a,b,c } from 'whatever'
import { x,y,x } from 'whatever2'

export default function(){
   // do the awesome thing
}
```

Ie.

```
// wrapped.js

let a = function(){ /* the imported thing */ }
let b = "something else imported"
// ... etc

export default function(){
   // do the awesome thing
}
```

Note that the imported modules also have further ES6 dependencies.

Is there any module bundler that can wrap this up into a single file with just the default export. I.e, everything is still ES6.

#### why?

I have a monorepo with lots of shared dependencies. However I need to use some of the code in a legacy system so want to avoid manually copying every single file that I need into a new repository.

- I can't use `lerna` because I can't publish all the dependencies.
- I can't get `webpack` to produce the right format for importing the `module` - see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56270596/create-es6-module-equivalent-using-webpack-output-target-options)
- I had a quick look at `rollup` but that does not seem to allow `ES6` as a target for bundling similar to `webpack`.

Comment: Take a closer look at rollup - it definitely does have ES6 module as an output format.

Comment: @Bergi - thanks will do.

Comment: @Bergi rollup can not generate single file for multiple inputs.

Comment: @AmirRezvani [Sure can?](https://rollupjs.org/tutorial/#creating-your-first-bundle)

Comment: @Bergi based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57162605/5330103

Comment: @AmirRezvani Ah what Rich is saying that you get one output per entrypoint. But it still bundles all the input modules that are imported by the respective entrypoint into a single module representing the whole bundle, which is what the OP was asking

Comment: @Begri how? every time it creates multiple files as output. if creates single file that would be like ```import "path/to/the/module"```

Comment: @Begri check this out, please.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77076188/rollup-js-combine-multiple-js-files-into-one-big-file