# How to configure in Rollup that will generate only single output file from multiple input files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, rollupjs

When configuring Rollupjs to generate a library, if the input is an array which consists of multiple javascript files. How can we do to these inputs will be generated in just a single output js file?

```
export const lgService = {
  input: [
    './src/app/services/livegiver/lgservices.js', 
    './src/app/services/readable-stream.js'
  ],
  output: {
    file: outputPath + 'LiveGiver/index.js',
    format: 'es'
  }
}
```

Expected:

```
  Input: [a.js, b.js]
  Output: dist/index.js
```

Actual:

```
  Input: [a.js, b.js]
  Output: dist/a.js; dist/b.js
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't — multiple inputs implies multiple outputs. To do what you're describing, you'll need to have a single entry module that looks something like this:

```js
import './app/services/livegiver/lgservices.js';
import './app/services/readable-stream.js';
```

If you need to generate that module dynamically you could use something like [rollup-plugin-virtual](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-virtual).

Answer (score 3):

You can import all your js files into index.js.
and export from index.js like the below

```
export { default as YourComponent} from "component path";
```

then in your rollup.config.js file.

```
export const lgService = {
  input: './src/app/index.js',
  output: {
    file: outputPath + '/index.js',
  }
}
```

this is tested in rollup v2.57.0