# Rollup.js - combine multiple js files into one big file

Tags: rollup, rtk-query, rollup-plugin-babel

I have  multiple files like this:

```
// File one
const A = CreateSomething();
export { A };
```

```
// File Two
import { A } from 'File One';
const other1 = A.injectSomething({ methodA: "a"}); 
export { other1 };
```

```
//File Three
import { A } from 'File One';
const other2 = A.injectSomething({ methodB: "b"}); 
export { other2 };
```

what I need is only one file in `dist` folder combining all this together. like so:

```
const A = CreateSomething();

const other1 = A.injectSomething({ methodA: "a"}); 
const other2 = A.injectSomething({ methodB: "b"}); 

export { A, other1, other2 };
```

how can I achieve this using Rollup?

Comment: i found the answer => I can not do that this way but here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159488/how-to-configure-in-rollup-that-will-generate-only-single-output-file-from-multi